# Compile XPath Abbreviated Query to Unabbreviated version

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers

The Xpath 3.1 presented by W3C includes the full grammar of the language with both abbreviated and unabbreviated syntax.

I am interested in references (if any) for any formal work done to compile/translate an XPath query in its abbreviated form to its equivalent in fully expanded unabbreviated form. Even work done on versions prior to 3.1 could be helpful.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#unabbrev https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#abbrev

Comment: This question asks for a software library, which is off-topic here. Are there any particular issues that make such a translation hard to implement using common techniques?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus You might be right, but I am looking for a formal research work done on the grammar translation. Would you mind listing the common techniques you referring to? It might be straightforward but I am a beginner on the subject.

Comment: You would use standard parsing techniques to parse the query into some intermediate form, and then traverse the intermediate form to output the fully expanded unabbreviated form.